# Waves in spaces of even dimension

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

In an article by Jim Holt, "Geometric creatures," he says:

> In a space with an odd number of dimensions, ... sound waves move
>   in a single sharp wave front.
>   But in spaces with an even number of dimensions, ... a noise-like
>   disturbance will generate a system of waves that reverberates forever.

Can someone please explain the mathematics behind this quote?

---

Jim Holt.
*When Einstein Walked with Gödel: Excursions to the Edge of Thought*.
Farrar, Straus and Giroux, 2018.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phenomenon behind this is usually referred to as Huygen's principle, and can be described a little bit more precisely as the following:

Say you have the solution $u(x,t)$ to an initial-value problem for the wave equation in $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$:

$$\Delta u - c^2 u_{tt} = 0,\quad u(x,0) = \phi,\quad u_t (x,0) = \psi$$

It turns out $u(x,t)$ depends *only* on the values of $\phi$ and $\psi$ on the surface of a ball $B$, centered at $x$ and of radius $ct$, for odd dimensions $n \geq 3$. Heuristically, that means the initial "disturbance" always propagates out at $c$, so the "size" of the nonzero part of the solution (support) is invariant with time. For even dimensions, the value of $u(x,t)$ is also dependent on everything *inside* that ball $B$ (i.e. things don't just propagate at $c$), so the "size" of the non-zero part of the solution (support) isn't invariant with time.

A short explanation of why it happens is as a result of the fact that there is no transformation in even dimensions that can turn a wave equation into a 1-D problem, which is the case for odd dimensions $n \geq 3$. It is more thoroughly described and fully derived in Evans' [book](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-19-r) or [here](http://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/waveequation3.pdf).

A slightly more beautiful but more esoteric explanation comes from [Balasz](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0370-1298/68/6/307/meta), who noted that one can obtain solutions to the wave equation by contour integration after performing a Wick rotation. The integrands of these possess a differing type of singularity based on the dimensional parity; a branch point in even dimensions and a pole in odd dimensions. And when calculating the value of the contour integral in the odd $n$ case, one needs to refer only to one time value (that of the pole), while this is impossible in the even $n$ case.

I should also point out that a system of waves in even dimensions actually does asymptotically decay to nothing everywhere inside of the ball $B$ (i.e. everything in the interior of $B$ eventually destructively interferes with itself), as shown in this [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82747873.pdf) by Bob Strichartz; he notes this can be used to justify why the classical prediction of certain observables emerges out of free quantum wave-functions. So take Jim Holt's statement with a grain of salt!

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The mathematics is explained [here](http://www.physics.iitm.ac.in/~labs/dynamical/pedagogy/vb/3dpart2.pdf). It discusses the behavior of the Green's function for the wave operator in various dimensions.